# how to send data to pyspark form inside python file?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have scraped the data from a website, it is a list of lists:

```
data = [
['name', '20 July 1995 08:05', 0, 'text text text'],
['name', '20 July 1995 08:05', 0, 'text text text'],
['name', '20 July 1995 08:05', 0, 'text text text'],
['name', '20 July 1995 08:05', 0, 'text text text']
]
```

Now I need to send it to pyspark for processing, do i need to use kafka? How to do it from vs studio IDE?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can launch a pyspark job/pyspark shell with whatever code you used to get the data. and then immediately convert to spark dataframes and use directly. Otherwise you could just dump as json and import in a separate spark job. I do not know if streaming is entirely necessary.

Comment: @JasonChia, u mean i can launch spark job from inside another python file?

Comment: No, you set up a session on spark. and then submit the job to spark.http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html